# How to run iPad 2 with iOS 9 emulator on Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ipad, ios9

My app is running fine on all ipad except iPad 2 with iOS 9.3.5. I don't have option to run emulator for the same ipad nor i have the same ipad. How to debug in this case? I am using react native just for the information.

User is able to install the app but it automatically closes in few mins after installing. I tried searching many things but couldn't find any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add iPad 2 Simulator to Xcode, from product, destination and add additional simulators at bottom, then in simulators section clicl on + to add new simulator and  then you can choose iPad 2 from there and iOS 9 as OS Version, You will have to download simulator runtime for iOS 9 then you can ad it.

Comment: I tried  that but issue is that i am not getting option for iOS 9 as i am using xcode 12.

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi then you might have to install xcode 11 or 10 from apple's website it would be available in resources section for developers.

Comment: in those you will have option to install more older version of ios then xcode 12